# why the build input file cannot be found ? even though the file is exist on the project directory?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have error like this:

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
>   '/Users/dev.adsapps/Documents/Lakuin/Lakuin_iOS/Versi1/project
>   file/Lakuin/Lakuin/Service/LocationService.swift' (in target 'Lakuin'
>   from project 'Lakuin')

even though I 100% sure the file is already exist on my project
[image]

but the error message is little bit weird, it is said .....Lakuin_iOS/Version1/project/.....

it is said **version1**  , but actually I run on ***version 2*** folder directory. so I have two folder

[image]

but even though I am in version 2 folder it seems it still connected to version1, the version2 folder is actually copy pasted folder from version1 with modification

so whats should I do ?

but it still doesn't work